# How to crop the long text as ... in ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

[image]

I have a long tittle below image but I need to trim it  and the image is not properly aligned how do I make it appear clear while viewing

Comment: did any answer not work for your?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**CSS**

```
.wrap-text {
  width: 250px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<h4 class="wrap-text">Sachin Ramesh Tendulkar is a former Indian international cricketer and a former captain of the Indian national team.</h4>
```

[working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-m4h968?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html)

Comment: In-case what if use want to show two or three lines of title and then ellipsis?

Answer (score 3):

Best way to trim text from last is to create your custom pipe and use it.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
 name: 'trimLast'
})

export class TrimLastPipe implements PipeTransform {

transform(value: string, args: string[]): string {
    const limit = args.length > 0 ? parseInt(args[0], 10) : 20;
    const trail = args.length > 1 ? args[1] : '...';
    return value.length > limit ? value.substring(0, limit) + trail : value;
   }
}
```

and then register this custom pipe to module. you can use it in entire application.